# Software Engineering site map

Tags: feature-request, site-attributes, hyperlinks

Does Software Engineering have a site map?

I've discovered the privileges page recently, which (as far as I know) doesn't have a link like profile or answers or flair. I wonder what other pages are there?

Comment: Related: [How can I view what privileges I have?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5548/how-can-i-view-what-privileges-i-have) - Also, you get a notification with a link to the privilege page _every time_ you get a new privilege, how come you only discovered it recently? You've received that notification 20 times already.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos, Relatively recently )))

Comment: To answer your question: No, there's no sitemap. There's a link to every publicly available page somewhere, but a lot of them are not particularly easy to find. The best place to start exploring is the links in the footer.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos, Please post that as an answer.

Comment: Well, you posted this as a feature request, I think I'll better leave it for the developers to answer. You could update the question to explicitly ask for a sitemap, and perhaps expand a bit on why it would be useful.